# Request cUrl in Curl

Tags: php, http, curl

I have action something like this

```
public function coordinatAction()
{
    $curl = curl_init('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=30.0000000000,40.0000000000');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $aParams);

    //Sending request
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    if (false === $result) {
        $sResult = curl_error($curl);
    };
    curl_close($curl);

    return $result;
}
```

And have unit test for this action:

```
public function coordinatActionTest()
{
    $curl = curl_init();
    $params = [/** Some Params */]
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://mysite.local/coordinate'); //path to my action
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($curl);

    $this->assertEquals(200, $httpCode, "Wrong HTTP Response Code");
}
```

When I execute test I get request "curl in curl" (curl in test call curl in action), but second curl is failed by time out after 5 minutes. If I call just one curl in action it everything ok, but duble curl is timed out. Could any explain why it happens

Comment: Mabye it's not related, but I see two things. In your function coordinatAction, aParams is never defined and function coordinatActionTest missing curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that the url is accessible using browser. `http://mysite.local/coordinate`. You can do it using curl command too to verfiy the link. For example:

```
curl -XPOST YOUR_URL -d _YOUR_PARAMS
```

Secondly, it can happen that your server doesn't accept any request without a proper user-agent string. I'ld recommend you to use `CURLOPT_USERAGENT` option with your curl test (with any browser like Opera or Mozila).

Finally, check your server's `httpd.conf` file and see what are the other parameters mandatory for an incoming request.